# React.js ASP.NET MVC core app hosted in IIS cannot read API (Controller) 404

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, asp.net-core, iis

I have been trying to access the controller methods (API) of my MVC.NET Core react application hosted on IIS. The application works perfectly except when fetching data from the API.

I am using the template project that visual studio 2019 creates. If I debug locally, the controller can be accessed. I have tried adding rules to the web.config and some working some settings in app.UseMvc(Routes).

Request URL:http://localhost:xx/api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts
Request method:GET
Status code: 404
Version:HTTP/1.1
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

```
fetch('api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
this.setState({ forecasts: data, loading: false });
});
```

The controller has the route : [Route("api/[controller]")]

It seems that it is trying to find a folder that has the path above and it its not finding it.

HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Has somebody encountered this? I want to get my app fully working in IIS before I star developing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy the app on IIS "usually" it runs on the default port 80 or 443 if https. Maybe your request is hitting the port you are using during development.

When on IIS try to remove the :xx part of your url

Comment: Hello, it is using the port I configured with IIS. It can request all the files of the application except when making calls to the controller. I added xx to not show the port because its irrelevant.

Comment: @Jose Lamboy Did you check if it is not [CORS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) related?

Comment: It is not CORS related. All is running under the same same origin.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem. I did not have .NET Core Run-time Installed on the server machine. https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download

To host the app in IIS it has to be pointing to the publish folder where your {application}.dll exist. From there it will read the config file and start the UI with the back-end.

Answer (score 0):

open terminal (on your project), run: `iisexpress-proxy 5000 to 5001`
and run your link.
good luck!

Answer (score 0):

my issue is with React, what happens is the url of the api becomes "localhost:80/client/build/api" something....

Comment: you need to set your path using the ROUTE method in the controller